# Pico .uf2 not moved to output via ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY

Tags: pi-pico, toolchain, binary-file

I wish to have the final .uf2 file destined for the Pico placed by the toolchain in a particular location. I have set this up using this command in `CMakeLists.txt`.

```
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin"
    ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin"
)
```

It DOES move the base object file to this directory (presumably due to the `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`), but NOT the final .uf2 binary file.

Any idea why this might be the case? I'm using Pico SDK 1.5.1 on Visual Studio, Windows.

A thought is that I do have the intermediary files during compilation moved to a non-standard location (as my source file tree is sync'd and I don't want to sync compilation files). This is set in the `CMakePresets.json` file using this line.

```
"binaryDir": "$env{TMP}/build/$env{PROJECT_NAME}",
```

Is it possible that I need to set something else in the `CMakePresets.json` file?